# WP_query paged pagination with excluded category still counts it

Tags: wp-query, pagination

So im making a custom WP_query loop with paged navigation. I want to show 4 posts per page in a specific category.

This is working fine, except the next_post_link() seems to still count the excluded catoegories when determining to show the link or not. How do i make sure that the post count is excluding the others categories, so that the next link only shows up if there is more then the 4 shown posts in that specific category?.

my code:

```
<div class="news-box-wrapper">
        <?php 

            $args = array ('post_type' => 'post','category__in' => array( 1 ), 'posts_per_page'=> 4, 'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),);
            $posts_query = new WP_query( $args );
        ?>


        <?php //Starts the news loop ?>
        <?php if ( $posts_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $posts_query->have_posts() ) : $posts_query->the_post(); ?>

            <article class="news-box">
                <?php //get the posts featured image in the right size = "featured-image" ?>
                <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'newsbox-image'); ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="Post image" width="700" height="400" />

                <div class="news-box-content">    
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <p class="news-date"><?php the_time('j F, Y'); ?></p>
                </div>

                <a class="read-more" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"></a>
            </article>
        <?php endwhile; else: endif;?>

    </div>

    <nav class="articles-nav">
        <?php previous_posts_link('Nyere'); ?><?php next_posts_link('Ældre'); ?>
    </nav>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Any help in understanding this is much appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix pagination for custom loops?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops)

Answer (score 1):

Okay found a solution as soon as i posted this. Typical google-syndrome huh? - i had to pass the WP_query variable to the max_num_pages var in my next_posts_link, so it looks like this:

```
<?php next_posts_link('Ældre', $posts_query->max_num_pages); ?>
```

guess same thing goes for the previous_posts_link